# Android activity error

Tags: android, android-activity

I am newbie in android. In android I trying to run a simple work. From my main.xml(http://pastebin.com/Mhgmpj4w) I have one button( my main.java(http://pastebin.com/b5irLVTc) ) it will switch to another activity the second.xml(http://pastebin.com/F92VxSEZ) where it will show some text ( my second.java(http://pastebin.com/MR3L5WXL) ) but there are some errors(http://pastebin.com/KH2wDh7b). I am a newbie please help me.

**main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**main.java:**

```
    package com.rana.activities;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class Main extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            Button b = (Button) findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
            b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Second.class));
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**second.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is the second activity" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**second.java:**

```
    package com.rana.activities;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class Second extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.second);
        }

    }
```

**logcat:**

```
    10-29 19:19:25.377: D/AndroidRuntime(859): Shutting down VM
    10-29 19:19:25.377: W/dalvikvm(859): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
    10-29 19:19:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(859): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    10-29 19:19:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(859): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rana.activities/com.rana.activities.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    10-29 19:19:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(859):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
    10-29 19:19:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(859):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
    10-29 19:19:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(859):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    10-29 19:19:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(859):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
    10-29 19:19:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(859):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    10-29 19:19:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(859):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    10-29 19:19:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(859):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    10-29 19:19:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(859):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    10-29 19:19:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(859):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    10-29 19:19:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(859):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    10-29 19:19:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(859):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    10-29 19:19:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(859):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    10-29 19:19:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(859): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    10-29 19:19:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(859):  at com.rana.activities.Main.onCreate(Main.java:18)
    10-29 19:19:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(859):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    10-29 19:19:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(859):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
    10-29 19:19:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(859):  ... 11 more
    <-------LogCat------------------->
```

Comment: Please accept the ans if it has solve the problem. and close the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace `android.R.id.button1` this with `R.id.button1` and import your own package `R` class in `main.java`. It will solve the problem. In this way it will allocated the memory from your application and hence it will not search for the global resouces

Comment: Thanks I replaced android.R.id.button1 with R.id.button1 but it didn't work. I didn't understand 'import your own package R class in main.java' can you explain it. But when I did it again it work. Perhaps the problem was with 'android.R.id.button1' and may be I import some unnecessary classes.

Comment: when you use android.R.id.button1 then it will import the package android.R which is not required in your case. so you need to use your own R.java file and the package for the same will be your main package name.R

Answer (score 1):

Just to help you debug your Android applications in the future the interesting lines of error are these:

```
10-29 19:19:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(859): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-29 19:19:25.397: E/AndroidRuntime(859):      at com.rana.activities.Main.onCreate(Main.java:18)
```

In line 18 of your Main.java file we have b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() and a NullPointerException. This exception is caused by line 17 in your code with Button b = (Button) findViewById(android.R.id.button1);

As Drax mentioned the error can easily be solved by supplying the correct id.

Good luck with your future developing in Android I hope you'll find it fun :-)

Comment: Thanks your way of debugging really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You clicked it!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class));


    }
```

} );

Hope that beginners strucking at this kind of problem will feel great.

Answer (score 0):

You should make entry of second.java file into the android Manifest file.
like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sevenapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.sevenapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="second"></activity>///Make entry here
    </application>

</manifest>
```