# Newbie Android NullPointerException Trouble Shooting

Tags: java, android, exception

I am having a similar problem as the person here: [Android activity error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977126/android-activity-error) I've read through the post. I also read through other posts. But I can't seem to get my Android application running.

Description: I have one button. I want this button to work. I keep getting an NPE because of an OnClickListener. This is virtually an identical problem as the above post, but mine is behaving a little differently. Please help me. Thank you very much.

Main.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class Main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Second.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Second.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Second extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Error Message

```
12-27 09:19:10.729: W/dalvikvm(923): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409951f8)
12-27 09:19:10.749: E/AndroidRuntime(923): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-27 09:19:10.749: E/AndroidRuntime(923): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.harryoh.firstapp/com.harryoh.firstapp.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-27 09:19:10.749: E/AndroidRuntime(923):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
12-27 09:19:10.749: E/AndroidRuntime(923):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
12-27 09:19:10.749: E/AndroidRuntime(923):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
12-27 09:19:10.749: E/AndroidRuntime(923):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
12-27 09:19:10.749: E/AndroidRuntime(923):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-27 09:19:10.749: E/AndroidRuntime(923):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-27 09:19:10.749: E/AndroidRuntime(923):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-27 09:19:10.749: E/AndroidRuntime(923):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-27 09:19:10.749: E/AndroidRuntime(923):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-27 09:19:10.749: E/AndroidRuntime(923):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-27 09:19:10.749: E/AndroidRuntime(923):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-27 09:19:10.749: E/AndroidRuntime(923):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-27 09:19:10.749: E/AndroidRuntime(923): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-27 09:19:10.749: E/AndroidRuntime(923):  at com.harryoh.firstapp.Main.onCreate(Main.java:19)
12-27 09:19:10.749: E/AndroidRuntime(923):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
12-27 09:19:10.749: E/AndroidRuntime(923):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
12-27 09:19:10.749: E/AndroidRuntime(923):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
12-27 09:19:10.749: E/AndroidRuntime(923):  ... 11 more
```

I really appreciate your help. I really want to learn Android, and these trouble shooting problems have always caused a lot of pain.

EDIT: Thanks for your help. I will return the favor to this community once I am able... I haven't gone through your inputs yet, since I wanted to provide this as requested. I will work on it now. I hope it works.

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you please provide your `main.xml` layout?

Comment: yes, a main.xml will help because as you can see you have an error 12-27 09:19:10.749: E/AndroidRuntime(923):  at com.harryoh.firstapp.Main.onCreate(Main.java:19) on line 19

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has happened to me numerous times while messing with layouts.  If you just recently added the button try refreshing the project and clean rebuilding and then see if it picks up the button.  For some reason if you add widgets and try to test them immediately after it doesn't actually update.

EDIT: After seeing your main.xml it looks like you dont even have a button set up. This would cause the null pointer exception because its looking for something that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

````
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Second extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
``` setContentView(R.layout.second);
    }
}

prove this, create new xml with name second and add setContentView(R.layout.second) in the class Second
````

Answer (score 0):

First, check if you've included Second activity in the manifest file. Second, there is no layout associated with the second activity. Try to add in the Second onCreate() `setContentView(R.layout.main);`

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare your second activity in your android manifest?

```
 <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".Second" >
  </activity>
```

Plus, you should add a layout for the second activity. Be sure to add in onCreate() of the Second activity a setContentView(R.layout.second)

Now that you provided your xml, notice that you dont have a button1 there,  you need to declare the button there before calling *findViewById()*.

After checking the above, try adding a button in your xml, inside your linear layout

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button1"     
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: This did solved it. I did not have Button declared in main.xml. I assumed that the main.xml code would appear if needed as soon as I drag and drop the button. But I guess it does not and I also have to write it out manually.

Comment: well, it should appear if you drag and drop the button. just to be sure, drag and drop it, and click twice on the button. it should put the cursor in the code that it generated. If the answer solved it pleace mark it as accepted. Here is the faq about how to make a good question. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask. Good luck in your studies.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're not calling `setContentView()` on your `Second` Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the OnClick event in code, why not set it up in your xml.

```
      <Button style="@style/WrapContent"
        android:onClick="buttonClicked"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/button_text" />
```

Then simply add the following method to your activity:

```
public void buttonClicked(View v) {

    // Handle Click Event
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Second.class) );

}
```

The View that gets passed in will be an instance of your button

Comment: possible, but it mixed code with layout. Not recommended if you stick to some programming paradigm

Comment: Specifically which android best practice are you referring to?  I think its prefectly okay to have view behavior included with view layout.  You are not handling the implementation in the xml, so that is still up to the activity.  You know how it if with design though, every one thinks their way is the best hehehe

Comment: The problem is basically, that if a designer creates the layout, he has to know the function name. Also renaming the name in code results in errors if you do not changed it in the layout, too. A best practice always reduce the number of possible failures. Your way is legit but I don't recommend it. But as you say: my way is the best hihi

Comment: Please read carefully. The avoided class loading is the result in implementing the OnClickListener interface with your activity and not with the call via xml: Documentation: `You may also find it more convenient to implement OnClickListener as a part of your Activity. This will avoid the extra class load and object allocation.`

Comment: Good catch, my approach is valid and documented.  I stand behind it.

Comment: And there is no problem with that :D